# Number doesn't update in setTimeout loop

Tags: javascript

This simple code should be counting from 0 to infinity and should be showing the next number every 100 milliseconds. The thing is when I open this in chrome the number is stuck at 0. Can somebody explain why this is happening and what I have done wrong?

```js
function count(a)
{
    var no=a;
    no++;

    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML=no;
    setTimeout("count(no)",100);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>



</head>
<body onload="count(-1);">

  <div id="num"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`. Pass a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a *string* to `setTimeout`, that will be executed as a code literal in the *global* scope. In the global scope, the variable `no` does not exist, because it's a variable scoped to the function `count`.

You'll want to pass the callback this way:

```
setTimeout(count, 100, no);
```

This passes the function object `count`, and the current value of `no` as an argument which will be passed to `count` when it's invoked.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that optional third parameter. Beautiful! If `setTimeout()` didn't allow that, you can always go with an anonymous function wrapper (which is a more generic approach that always works).

Comment: So basicly i wanted to send a function to setTimeout, but instead i sent a string right?

Comment: Yes. You *can* send a string, but that loses all context, which was your problem.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're passing a string to `setTimeout`. As [the MDN documentation for `setTimeout`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html#Passing_string_literals) states:

> String literals are evaluated in the global context, so local symbols in the context where `setTimeout()` was called will not be available when the string is evaluated as code.

That is, 100 milliseconds after `count` has returned, `"count(no)"` is evaluated in the global context. `count` is a global function, but `no` was just a local variable. There is no global symbol `no`.

To fix this, don't use strings. Pass a function to `setTimeout` instead:

```
setTimeout(function () { count(no); }, 100);
```

The `function () { count(no); }` part is what's known as a *closure*, a function that uses local variables from a surrounding scope. This way you can refer to a local variable like `no` even after its containing function has returned.

In theory you could also do

```
setTimeout(count, 100, no);
```

but MDN warns:

> Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap the function reference in quotes, instead pass an *anonymous function* that calls `count` (and holds a reference to `no` as a *closure*):

```js
function count(a) {
  var no = a;
  no++;

  num.textContent = no;
  setTimeout(function() { count(no); }, 100);
}
```

```html
<body onload="count(-1)">

  <div id="num"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -4):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var no = 0;
    function count()
    {
            no++;
            document.getElementById("num").innerHTML=no;

    }
    setInterval(count, 100);
</script>

<body>

    <div id="num"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: The question is "*Can somebody explain why this is happening and what I have done wrong?*" Your answer just says "*try this*". You should at least explain what your new code does and how it's different.